# How to correctly insert a leading space in a line?

Tags: spacing

```
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \textit
    {
        Research Intern\\
        \href{http://www.department.com}{~Department Name}\\
        ~University Name\\
    }
\end{minipage}
```

In the above code segment `{~Department Name}` correctly shows a leading white space but `~University Name` does not renders the leading white space. I am new to latex, if someone could guide me towards the correct usage standards, that would be great.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Spaces are normally removed after line breaks; you may want something like `\hspace*{1em}` instead of `~`. I also suggest to say `\itshape` and to remove the braces instead of `\textit{...}`: it's simpler and clearer; the effect of `\itshape` is confined to the `minipage`.

Answer (score 5):

A variant with the plain tex commands `\hangindent, \hangafter`. It allows grouping all specifications at the beginning of the minipage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
  \itshape\hangindent=1em\hangafter=1
  %
  Research Intern\\
  \href{http://www.department.com}{Department Name}\\
  University Name
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Spaces are normally removed after line breaks, in order to preserve justification on both sides.

You can use `\hspace*` that isn't removed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\itshape
Research Intern\\
\hspace*{1em}\href{http://www.department.com}{Department Name}\\
\hspace*{1em}University Name
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

The `em` unit is relative to the current font (more or less the width of “M”, but not necessarily). Adjust to your preference.

The `~` in the second argument of `\href` wasn't removed, because TeX inserts a “whatsit” for the hyperlink before the second argument; but it's better to have a consistent syntax.

Note that you don't need `\textit{...}`, using `\itshape` makes for easier input and its effect is only in the scope of `minipage`. Finally, remove the trailing `\\` that would just cause an `Underfull \hbox` warning and bad spacing.

[image]